# alertdialog shows no text

Tags: java, android

I have a problem creating an AlertDialog.
No matter what i do, the title and the message are always empty
here is my code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BigActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder
                    .setTitle(item.getTitle())//no problem whith getters
                    .setMessage(item.getMessage())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cerrar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                ;
            AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

any help would be appreciated

P.S.

```
System.out.println(item.getTitle()+" "+item.getMessage())
```

works ok.

Comment: what is this `item` ?

Comment: i can't post de source code of that, but is a data container.
the method item.getMessage() is something like: 

"return string1+string2+string3"

item.getTitle() is similar.

Comment: no but it has information from one.

Comment: Have you checked this statement inside AlertDialog block `System.out.println(item.getTitle()+" "+item.getMessage());`

Comment: yes, that is why i said it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to string using `toString()` function like:

```
.setMessage(item.getMessage().toString())
```

Comment: no, this is not the problem :C, btw the getters return strings.
anyways i tried with no positive result.

Comment: Could you try this then. Just a guess though. Try create first and then add title and message : AlertDialog.Builder DialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BigActivity.this).create();

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add show()

```
Dialog.show();
```

It would also be better if you follow the coding guidelines to use a lowercase letter for the first variable name character.

Comment: I think he is able to see alertDialog. The message and title field is empty. He needs to convert item values to sting using toString() function..

Comment: oh my mistake, at the copy of the code i forgot that line (i'm going to fix it), btw the names of variables where changed. In the real code the guideline is followed. (fixing that also)

Comment: @Sushil I tested the code and even without the toString() function it displays the title and message.

OP are the title and message values String?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to see the Dialog window (and you are not calling this in the background thread) then the only possible reason could be is that **both text and background colors are same**. Try to change the text color using either of the following method:

1. Using Inline HTML

   .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("item.getMessage()")
2. Custom layout theme.

   [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

Comment: 1.- same result.
2.- if you mean "AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int theme)", is not available for api level 7 and i really need this api level.

Comment: After alert.show(), try following code to debug the string and text color because there doesn't seem to be any other reason. 
alert.getWindow().getAttributes();TextView textView = (TextView) TextView alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

String txt = textView.getText().toString();
textView.getTextColors().toString(); // gives text colors in different state